# Почему SharePref реагирует на название таблицы?

Tags: java, android

Такая ситуация, у меня есть класс с `SharePref`-сами , и каждому я присваивал свое название таблицы и свое название переменной.

Вот так

```
public static void saveA(Context context, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("keyA", value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isA(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean("keyA", false);
}

public static void saveB(Context context, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("B", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("keyB", value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isB(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("B", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean("keyB", false);
}
```

Но потом подумал о том, что код дублируется и обьединил это все вот таким образом

```
public static void savePref(Context context, String key, Object value) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();

    if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    } else if (value instanceof String) {
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
        editor.putLong(key, (Long) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
    }

    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isBooleanShared(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Теперь у меня не создается отдельная таблица для каждого преференса, теперь она одна для всех `SHARED_PREF_NAME` и данные в ней отличаются по ключам...

Для сохранения я передаю в функцию `savePref(Context context, String key, Object value)`  ключ любого конкретного значения и его `value`...

И потом когда мне нужно достать это значение я передаю в функцию `isBooleanShared(Context context, String key)` ключ нужного мне значения и получаю его...

Так вот в конкретном примере когда я первый раз запускаю приложение это означает, что таблица еще даже не создана. Я на первом экране делаю вызов вот этой функции

```
public static boolean isBooleanShared(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

передаю мой ключ и поскольку в таблице еще нет никакой записи я ожидаю получить значение которое указал как дефолтное `sPref.getBoolean(key, false);` - `false` , но по непонятной причине мне возвращается `true`...

Как я это исправил. Я опять разделил этот метод так сказать вернулся к тому что было, но имя таблицы оставил такое же вот так получилось

```
public static void saveLogIn(Context context, String key, Object value){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isLogIn(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

и опять получил `true` вместо `false`, далее я поменял имя таблицы и тогда все заработало правильно

```
public static void saveLogIn(Context context, String key, Object value){
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("Log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean isLogIn(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences("Log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPref.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Но в таком случае не понятно, почему когда я первый раз загружаю приложение и пробую получить значение из таблицы с общим именем для всех то мне не возвращается дефолтное значение, а когда делаю то же самое но присваиваю другое имя этой таблице то все работает как ожидается?

Comment: SHARED_PREF_NAME должен быть не константой, а передаваться в качестве аргумента в зависимости от того, какое название таблицы вам надо. Хотя я и не понимаю, зачем эти сложности и почему бы не писать все в один файл SharedPreferences

Comment: Так я как раз и хочу писать все в один файл, в этом и проблема. Когда пишу в разные файлы все работает, когда пишу в один то не работет... Только насчет константы не понял, в виде константы я передаю имя таблицы в которую и хочу писать все ключи с их значениями

Comment: А... Если раньше (в предыдущих тестах\запусках приложения) вы что то записали по данному ключу в таблицу с именем SHARED_PREF_NAME, то дефолтное значение такой таблице при новых запусках присваиваться не будет. Файл `SharedPreferences` и все его ключи и их значения сохраняется до деинсталяции приложения, а не до выхода из приложения. В общем попробуйте деинсталировать приложение с устройства и потом уже продолжать.